# How can start Linux init script service of Geoserver

Tags: linux, ubuntu, geoserver

I downloaded Linux init script from geoserver [web site](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/production/linuxscript.html). And I moved it to `/etc/init.d`
[image]

geoserver color is different from other services. But when I run start service command it does not work. How can I start this service. How can I show linux this is a service.

Comment: How is this related to coding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should make it executable.

```
chmod +x geoserver
```

Answer (score 1):

First thing you have to change the permission of script.

```
chmod 755 geoserver
```

then you can start your service by either of these commands

```
/etc/init.d/geoserver start
```

Or if your system have initctl then you can also use

```
sudo initctl start geoserver
```

Or if your system having systemctl

```
sudo systemctl start geoserver
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to run this two commands:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/geoserver
sudo update-rc.d geoserver defaults
```

After that `sudo service geoserver start` worked just fine